# Conversion Error during database UPDATE

Tags: c#, asp.net, date-conversion

I am entering the current date to a SQL database using an ASP.NET form. The conversion failed when converting date time from string. This is the code I'm using.

```
txt_OrderDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: if txt_OrderDate.Text is of type string, and so it would seem, that should work. Your error must be happening somewhere else. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: update your question to add database insert/update code

Comment: string query9 = "Update Order_Production SET Delivery_Date='" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox11.Text.ToString()) + "' WHERE OP_ID='" +DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"';";
 mainclass.Updates(query9);

Comment: Why are you doing a Convert.ToDateTime? it is valid syntax to have the date as a string inside two single quotes. Also is TextBox11 the same as txt_OrderDate?

Comment: because the requirement is to convert the date to string while passing it to the database and the data type in the database is date. I removed the single quotes and still it gives the error.

Comment: examples you posted should have worked. Can you post the rest of the code you are using as the error may be there? Also, make sure you have runat="server" on the TextBox itself.

Comment: Can you write complete error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BG9;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    ad1.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into test_date values (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'" + TextBox1.Text+"',120))", con);
    ad1.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: i want to insert the data in the format of Date only. from what i can understand here you are passing it to the database as a string. am i correct?

Comment: In database field datatype is datetime and I am pass string format from here. if your format is different  then please provide your format.

Comment: This is the format I need the SQL table to hold yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: use sql function convert and your query will be                    ( insert into test_date values (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'" + TextBox1.Text+"',120))", con);

Answer (score 1):

1. This is dangerouse way to do like that. Suggest to use Sql Parameters instead.
2. Use its this way.

   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_OrderDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
3. Then pass dt value to SQL Parameter.
4. Example of using Sql Parameter from MSDN:

   private static void UpdateDemographics(Int32 customerID,
               string demoXml, string connectionString)
           {
               // Update the demographics for a store, which is stored 
               // in an xml column. 
               string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
                   + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

   ```
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
           command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
           command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

           // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
           // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

           try
           {
               connection.Open();
               Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_OrderDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); is this a possibility? I changed yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm  to yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: I don't know what is default culture of your application, so you must just try. Actually this must work.